# How to disable the MacBook screen when connected to TV via HDMI

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, television

How can I disable the MacBook screen when it is connected to my TV via HDMI?B

Comment: How is it connected to your tv. Cable (which) Airplay (what option in use)

Comment: I connected it using HDMI.

Comment: I should have also asked which macbook model as it may make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your MacBook in clamshell mode, which disables the internal display, by closing the lid when your Mac is connected to the display (and AC power is connected). You can then use an external keyboard and mouse to use the computer.

Opening the lid restores the internal display, however you can set it so that the display stays disabled after opening using the following boot argument, then reboot once to enable the new setting:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="iog=0x0"
```

<sup>Reset using `sudo nvram -d boot-args` or by resetting NVRAM by booting with ⌘⌥PR.</sup>

Comment: Under windows I can just choose the screens I want to enable. Isn't there an equivalent on Mac for it? I want to leave it opened because I don't have an external keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Okay I tried this. Does work, it's a little bit cumbersome though.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I would like to add another solution for it.

Instead of disabling the screen with a software setting (and having to disable the newly introduced csrutil through recovery mode) and maybe having it not work, you can simply place a very weak magnet (like a fridge magnet) between the keyboard and the headphone jack.

Credit to reddit user [raif_](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/5ehubw/disabling_internal_display/dackm3z/), who also posted a youtube vid showing the exact procedure.